# keras cnn training accuacy and loss do not change and val loss and accuracy remains 0

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

i am working on face expression classification problem, i downloaded some images from internet and some i clicked by myself of expression happy (100 pics), sad(100 pics), neutral(50 pics) and distracted(50) pics, as the data is very less i am using data augmentation and training a CNN from the example in keras documentation, also as i am working on kaggle notebook i am not saving the augemted data i am converting to array and appending with the original data.
you can try the code yourself at [avidavi](https://www.kaggle.com/avidavi/expression-detect/)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dropout, Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.utils import np_utils

#loading from csv
train = pd.read_csv(r'/kaggle/input/traindata/train.csv')
#each row is of 9217 features in which first 9216(96*96) are image converted to array 
#and last column is label
#labels = {1:'happy', 2:'sad', 3:'neutral', 4:'distracted'}
#below i am defining data generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.0,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=False,
    fill_mode='nearest')

#below converting array for suitable shapes for keras, as these are gray scale images so 1 channel
train_array = train.values
print(train_array.shape)
y_train_array= train_array[:,-1]
X_train_array = train_array[:,:-1].reshape(train_array.shape[0],96,96,1)
# del train_array
print(X_train_array.shape, y_train_array.shape)

#below creating 20 more images for each image and creating a new array
X_test_arr = []
y_test_arr = []
for i in range(X_train_array.shape[0]):
    j=0
    for batch in datagen.flow(x=X_train_array[i].reshape(1,96,96,1), y=y_train_array[i].reshape(1,), batch_size=1):
        j+=1
        X_test_arr.append(batch[0].reshape(96,96))
        y_test_arr.append(batch[1])
        if j == 20:
            break

#even though i am creating 20 or 50 augmented images or normalizing them or converting to int 
# output accuracy does not change

#creating arrays from above list
y_aug_arr = np.array(y_test_arr)
X_aug_arr = np.array(X_test_arr)

#appending augmented data to original data
X_train_array = np.r_[X_train_array, X_aug_arr]
y_train_array = np.r_[y_train_array, y_aug_arr]

#reshaping for keras input
X_train_array = X_train_array.reshape(X_train_array.shape[0], X_train_array.shape[1], X_train_array.shape[2], 1)

#creating model, i have used adam, rmsprop accuracy does not change while using SGD accuracy drops to almost 0
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(96, 96, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

#fitting model
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2
history = model.fit(X_train_array, y_train_array.reshape(-1), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)

#output is same no matter what i do
Epoch 1/2
200/200 [==============================] - 34s 169ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.3957 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
200/200 [==============================] - 34s 168ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.3957 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: To get a good answer, I recommend that you improve the code you've included... It should be the shortest amount of code you can find which demonstrates the problem you have. It should also include the imports you have to your program.

Comment: @Arkleseisure thanks for the input, i will add the imports, but full code is necessary as i am not sure which step i am doing mistake

Comment: The last dense layer must have a dimensionality equal to your classes

Comment: @MarcoCerliani i did that but i was getting dimension mismatch error, then i one hot encoded the labels and its working fine now, now my training accuracy is increasing but my validation accuracy is very bad like for first epoch it is 30 % then it starts dropping, is it because 90 % of my data is augmented data ?, but in keras example for data augmentation they are training for only 2000 examples with data augmentation and getting good accuracy, anything you can think of which can improve the model, can you can click on the kaggle link if you have time and look